# ANN Implementation Overfitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new in ML field and learning it, I made a model by following a tutorial but resulted accuracy is always jumps to 100% soon. I searched online and find about it that i have issue related to model overfitting according to my understanding. Dataset i have used is pretty small from UCI site named Indian Liver Patients Dataset. The dataset contains very few observation around 600.

My Question is how i could overcome this overfitting in the data. Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("C:/TF/TEST/ILDP.csv")

df["ag_ratio"].fillna("0.6", inplace=True)

df.isnull().sum()

print(df.head())

LD, NLD = df['is_patient'].value_counts()

df_sex = pd.get_dummies(df['gender'])
df_new = pd.concat([df, df_sex], axis=1)

Droop_gender = df_new.drop(labels=['gender'], axis=1)
Droop_gender.columns = ['age', 'tot_bilirubin', 'direct_bilirubin', 'tot_proteins', 'albumin', 'ag_ratio',
                        'sgpt', 'sgot', 'alkphos', 'Female', 'Male', 'is_patient']

X = Droop_gender.drop('is_patient', axis=1)
y = Droop_gender['is_patient']

print(X.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier = Sequential()  # Initialising the ANN

classifier.add(Dense(units=16, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))
classifier.add(Dense(units=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# compile ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fitting the data
histroy = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=50)


y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = [1 if y >= 0.5 else 0 for y in y_pred]

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: You have 583 total samples with 10 features. And then you use 16x8x8x1 network. This looks like way too complex topology to me. For non deep learning tasks you rarely need more than 1 hidden layer. So try less neurons and just one hidden layer. You can add the regularizer as well - https://keras.io/regularizers/. Plot some learning curves using k-fold cross-validation to confirm the overfitting. Ah, and I didn't download the dataset - are you sure you shuffled it and not looking only at positive cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your model is overfitting is encouraging because it means your model has the capacity to learn. Now you have to gradually reduce the capacity of your model to make it generalize better. My recommendation is to add regularization.

Add dropout layers between some of your fully connected layers:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=16, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(units=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
```

You can add these [dropout](https://medium.com/@amarbudhiraja/https-medium-com-amarbudhiraja-learning-less-to-learn-better-dropout-in-deep-machine-learning-74334da4bfc5) layers between any layers, but adding between layers with more neurons is better.

If that doesn't work well you can try weight decay. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
from keras import regularizers
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
```

Although try either kernel_regularize or activity_regularizer first. They should both work about the same anyway. Try tuning and see how different parameters change. In the end it's a lot of black magic so you'll have to experiment a bit. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response 
i have done the following changes 
1) data shuffling  df.sample(frac=1) 
2) classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)) between the layers
3) validation_split=0.33
It is displaying a slight change in its Training process . . . . but accuracy is still achieving 100%. 
My Next step would be to find selected attributes that have precedent in decision making from same dataset even though has only 11 features. and try to compare it will standard classification models. Need Help

Comment: 100% accuracy isn't always a bad thing, how is your validation accuracy?

Comment: epos1 (loss: 0.6915 - acc: 0.7399 - val_loss: 0.6899 - val_acc: 0.7259)
epos 50 (loss: 0.1777 - acc: 0.9707 - val_loss: 0.1695 - val_acc: 0.9852)

Comment: Hey that's great! Your validation accuracy is really good and has gone up since epoch 1. Just because your training accuracy is better does not mean your model is overfitting. It is only overfitting when your validation accuracy peaks and then gets worse.